# Check if multipolygon contains point in GeoDjango

Tags: gis, postgis, geodjango

I have a MultiPolygon field, `preferences.locations`, and a Point field, `rental.location`. When querying to check whether a rental's location is contained by `preferences.locations`, the query is only successful if the `rental.location` is contained by the first polygon in the `preferences.locations` MultiPolygon.

For example, with these geometries:

```
point1 = (81.20141954209073, -129.891357421875)
point2 = (40.70875101828792, -73.93179774284363)

preferences.locations = MultiPolygon(
    Polygon(((81.14748070499664, -163.289794921875),

              point1, # contains the first point

              (81.14748070499664, -163.289794921875),
              (81.14748070499664, -163.289794921875),)),

    Polygon(((40.70718949655447, -73.98123621940613),

              point2, # contains the second point

              (40.683762276904055, -73.99702906608582),
              (40.70718949655447, -73.98123621940613),)),
)

rental1.location = Point(*point1)

rental2.location = Point(*point2)
```

When querying to check which rentals' locations are contained by `preferences.locations`, while both rentals should be returned, only the first rental is returned.

```
>>> Rental.objects.filter(location__contained=preferences.locations)
[<Rental: Rental object>] # rental1
```

How can I successfully check which rentals' locations are contained by `preferences.locations` (no matter which Polygon they're contained by).

Answer (score 10):

The proper way to check whether a Point is contained by a MultiPolygon is to use `point.intersects(multipolygon)`.

```
>>> Rental.objects.filter(location__intersects=preferences.locations)
[<Rental: Rental object>, <Rental: Rental object>]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm confused by the distinction, tho: why are points not `contained` but `intersect`ing?

Comment: Check out this answer for a detailed explanation: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108536